# Determinant of transpose intuitive proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, exterior-algebra, transpose

We are using Artin's Algebra book for our Linear Algebra course. In Artin, det(A^T) = det(A) is proved using elementary matrices and invertibility. All of us feel that there should be a 'deeper' or a more fundamental or a more intuitive proof without using elementary matrices or invertibility. The one our prof came up with used linear transformations between tensor algebras, wedges and exterior algebras which we do not understand.
Are there any other proofs for det(A^T) = det(A) ? Edit: also, is there a geometric proof? For the 2*2 case at least?

Comment: I think it's fairly intuitive using the "big sum" formula for the determinant (the formula where you have $n!$ terms in the sum, each term corresponding to one possible permutation).

Comment: Have you seen $$Det(A) = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} sgn(\sigma) a_{1,\sigma(1)}a_{2,\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{n,\sigma(n)}$$ this definition before?

Comment: I feel like there should be a geometric way to argue it since the determinant is related to the volume of the parallelepiped generated by the columns.

Comment: I feel the same.  But I've been thinking about it for a while now and I haven't come up with a completely geometric way, yet.  The problem is that the rows and columns of a matrix are really in different spaces.  The only real connection I see between them is algebraic.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, so that there exists an invertible matrix $C$ such that $D=CAC^{-1}$ is diagonal, then $D=D^t=(CAC^{-1})^t=C^{-t}A^tC^t$. Since $D$ and $D^t$ have the same determinant, simply because the two matrices are in fact equal, it follows at once from this that $A$ and $A$ and $A^t$ have the same determinant.

As diagonalizable matrices are dense in $M_n(\mathbb C)$, and the map $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)\mapsto \det(A)-\det(A^t)\in\mathbb C$ is continuous, we see at once that this function is in fact constant. What you want follows from this.

Comment: This shows that what you want works  for complex matrices. Since $\det(A)$ and $\det(A^t)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients in the entries of $A$, it follows easily from that that what you want also works for matrices in every commutative ring.

Comment: Otherwise, notice that to prove this for a fields it is enough to prove it for the algebraic closure of the field, and use the Zariski topology on $M_n$.

Answer (score 3):

The determinant of a matrix does not change when you compute it via cofactor expansion along column or row. Thus expanding along a row in $A$ is equivalent to expanding along a column in $A^t$. I'm not sure if this is what you meant by "using invertibility".