# Relationship between two given determinants .

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

. Let $D1$ = det $\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b & c \\
    x & y & z \\
    p & q & r \\
    \end{pmatrix}$
 and $D2$ = det$\begin{pmatrix}
    -x & a & -p \\
    y & -b & q \\
    z & -c & r \\
    \end{pmatrix}
  $

$(i)D_1=D_2\ \ \ \ \ \ $   $(ii)D_1=2D_2\ \ \ \ $ $(iii)D_1=-D_2\ \ \ \ $ $(iv)D_2=2D_1\ \ \ \ $

I am trying to find out the relation between given deteriminants so I am using some properties of determinants on $D_2$

$D2$ = $\begin{vmatrix}
    -x & a & -p \\
    y & -b & q \\
    z & -c & r \\
    \end{vmatrix}
   \implies (-1)\begin{vmatrix}
    x & -a & p \\
    y & -b & q \\
    z & -c & r \\
    \end{vmatrix} \text{Took $(-1)$ common from first row}$

$\implies (1)\begin{vmatrix}
    x & a & p \\
    y & b & q \\
    z & c & r \\
    \end{vmatrix} \text{Took $(-1)$ common from $2nd$ column}$

$\implies(-1)\begin{vmatrix}
    a & x & p \\
    b & y & q \\
    c & z & r \\
    \end{vmatrix} \text{interchanged first and 2nd column}$

$\implies(-1)D_1$

I don't have an answer available for this question so I want to know if I did it right? Can anyone tell me any other way of solving this? I Just wanna know any other method.

Comment: Have you tried calculating explicitly the determinant? It's a 3 by 3 matrix, so it should be easy.

Comment: You solved it correctly. In the last step you are using $|A|=|A^T|$. Sanity check: consider $a=y=r=1$ and others are $0$, $|D_1|=1,|D_2|=-1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468064/determinant-of-transpose-intuitive-proof

Comment: @Andrei It came in one mark so I tried to find out quick way. Although I didn't try it.